# Julia Beginner: How do I add a new column of data based on values in another column

Tags: dataframe, julia

I'm sure this is a very simple question, but please have patience - very new to this.

I have a DataFrame with data including sex, earnings and if a record is "old" or "new". I want to add a new column to this DataFrame, with the value coming from one of four sources (columns) based on if they are M/F and old/new, and also matched to the earnings value.

In excel, I would have used index(Match()) to lookup row based on earnings, and columns based on M/F, old/new.

I've created 4 dictionaries for each of the sources and I can return the value I want for a specific earnings value, but I'm struggling to get this to work for all rows and values of earnings.  I've tried a function:

```
function SizeCoeff(x)
if Sex=="M" && Type == "Old"
    get(MaleOldSizeEffect,x,0)
elseif Sex=="F" && Type == "Old"
    get(FemaleOldSizeEffect,x,0)
elseif Sex=="F" && Type == "New"
    get(FemaleNewSizeEffect,x,0)
else get(MaleNewSizeEffect,x,0)
end
end

SizeCoeff.(earnings)
```

but this isn't working and is returning the default value for all rows (not to mention probably quite clunky)

I have joined the sources of data to my main df using innerjoin, which takes care of the matching based on earnings, but I'm struggling to only pick up the source that I want based on the final two conditions.

I've been researching all day and have tried transform, subsets, grouped dataframes - I feel like there must be a , so any tips would be gratefully received (and apologies for butchering this code!)

Edit: First two lines of my DF - can't get it to display unless i use a screengrab. [The figures in yellow are what I'm trying to produce.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3gl7.png)

Comment: Can you add an example of what your dataframe looks like right now, and what it would look like with the new column added to it? It's hard to figure out exactly what you're trying to do based on text description alone.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what role earnings play in this, or how exactly the coefficients are assigned (for eg., why there are two values under `Male_Old`, 1 and 5). But here's an example of adding a column to a DataFrame based on the values of two existing columns:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(Policy_No = [1, 2], 
                      Sex = [:M, :F], 
                      Type = [:Old, :New]) #create the DF
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ Policy_No  Sex     Type   
     │ Int64      Symbol  Symbol 
─────┼───────────────────────────
   1 │         1  M       Old
   2 │         2  F       New

julia> sizecoeffs = (M = (Old = 1, New = 2), 
                     F = (Old = 7, New = 8));

julia> transform!(df, [:Sex, :Type] =>
                      ByRow((sex, type) -> sizecoeffs[sex][type]) =>
                      :Coeff)
2×4 DataFrame
 Row │ Policy_No  Sex     Type    Coeff 
     │ Int64      Symbol  Symbol  Int64 
─────┼──────────────────────────────────
   1 │         1  M       Old         1
   2 │         2  F       New         8
```

Let me know if this helps, and what missing in it with respect to your use case.

Comment: Thank you for this, this is really helpful.  So I need the sizecoeffs variable to be arrays themselves, which I've been able to define using `sizecoeffs=(M = (Old = MalePSizeEffect, New= MalePSizeEffect), 
           F = (Old= MalePSizeEffect, New= MalePSizeEffect));` and thats working fine, but when I add that to the transform its basically adding the full dataframe for the OldMale in the coeff column. I think transform is what I need, I'm just struggling to get it to do what I want!

Comment: Follow up comment - I think what I really want is an innerjoin from Male/Old, FemaleNew, etc based on the Sex and Type!

Comment: I [created a chat room for this question](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246822/discussing-https-stackoverflow-com-q-73129018) since we'll probably need some more back and forth information to figure things out. Could you please join [the chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246822/discussing-https-stackoverflow-com-q-73129018)?

Comment: Thank you so much - however I can't use the chatroom as I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: I upvoted your question so hopefully now you do :) But even if it doesn't, you should at least have read access now, so you can reply here in case it doesn't allow you to write in chat.